# Determine the value

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $(u_n)$ is given recursively as follows: 
$$\begin{cases}
u_1=\frac{1}{1+x}\\ 
\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{u^2_{n}}-\frac{1}{u_n}+1, &\forall n\geq 1
\end{cases}$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R},x\neq 1$
Let $S_n=u_1+u_2+...+u_n$ and $P_n=u_1u_2...u_n$
Determine the value of the following expression $xS_n+P_n$

Comment: Is this a homework/contest question ? Sometimes these recurrence relations don't have a closed form, and I'd like to know if it's a question that you read or a question that you came up with.

Comment: $\frac{1}{u_{n^2}}$ or $\frac{1}{u_n^2}$?

Comment: @BorisNovikov This is a good question as well

Comment: I think $u_n^2$, otherwise $(u_n)$ is not recursively defined

Comment: Sorry, that is $\frac{1}{u^2_{n}}$, I edited

Comment: Is $a$ supposed to be $x$??

Answer (score 1):

1) Prove by induction that 
$P_n=\frac{xu_{n+1}}{1-u_{n+1}}$ :
$$
P_n=u_n P_{n-1}=\frac{xu_n^2}{1-u_{n}} =\frac{xu_n}{\frac{1}{u_{n}^2}-\frac{1}{u_{n}}} =\frac{x}{\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}-1} =\frac{xu_{n+1}}{1-u_{n+1}}
$$

2) Prove by induction that $xS_n+P_n=1$. Suppose $xS_{n-1}+P_{n-1}=1$. Then substituting 1), we have

$$
xS_n+P_n=xu_n+xS_{n-1}+P_n =xu_n+1-P_{n-1}+P_n =\ldots =1
$$